# Web page loading in IE is slower than others browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web-applications, optimization, loading

I made a web page where I use "*a lot of*" jQuery plugins and custom made functions. Page is using Codeigniter PHP framework and MySQL database.

I've noticed that in other browsers work relatively quickly, even in IE work relatively quickly but the problem I see is that at the end of the page (which is already loaded) IE still loading something and I do not know what. And because of this loading a whole page "freezes" for a few seconds. But only in IE.

I've put my scripts at the bottom of document. I am also using minified scripts.

What am I doing wrong or am I missing something here?

Web page is located here: [www.publishwall.si](http://www.publishwall.si)

Regards, Mario

Comment: Run through a HTTP proxy like Fiddler and see if there are any resources requested at the end that take up time.

Comment: Everything is fine in here. IE7, IE8 and IE9. I used developer bar with Net tab and everything is loading okay

Comment: I will test on other computers in IE. In my IE this is still a problem... In Fiddler I didn't find anything wrong.

Comment: I found a very good "solution" [LABjs](http://happyworm.com/blog/tag/labjs/). In my IE problem is solved.. So I think the problem is solved, but I still need to check with my customers..

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing using Visual Studio?

If so, make sure that "browser link" is disabled.